# Binding to specific part of a complex list

Tags: binding, winrt-xaml

I have a complex list as a resource in the following form:-

```
sectionList
       Sections
               Section 0
               Section 1
               .
               .
               Section 12
```

Each of those have few properties like 'Name', ie. Section 0 have a property 'Name' and so on.

In my Xaml i have a ComboBox which i want to bind it's ItemsSource to get the Name property of each Section in this ComboBox. When i use ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Section}" i get only a list of the Types not the actual Name property. With that i mean the list looks like below:-

```
AppName.ClassName+Section  (This is the Type)
AppName.ClassName+Section
.
.
.
AppName.ClassName+Section
```

So my question is, how to get the property Name instead of the Type in this ComboBox?

Hope this an enough discription otherwise i will be more than glad to explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 'DisplayMemberName' on the combobox to pass in the name of the field you wish to display.

See [WPF Combobox DisplayMemberPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460612/wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath) for a usage example (use the solution, not the question as it is incorrect!)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is really easy and WORKING, tho after i asked the q. i found out that you can even do it using the DataTemplate. Really Thanks dude.