# ComboBox for enumeration System.IO.Ports.Parity in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox

I want (in C#) to populate the list of admissible values for a combobox with the admissible values of the enumeration `System.IO.Ports.Parity`. To this end I created a collection:

```
public class theParitySource : ObservableCollection<Parity>
{
    public theParitySource()
    {            
        Array parities = System.Enum.GetValues( typeof( Parity ) );
        foreach (Parity p in parities) this.Add(p);            
    }
}
```

(btw: is there oneliner for this initialization?) and made this the datacontext of the combobox:

```
  ...
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:myNamespace"
  ...

  <ComboBox ...>
      <ComboBox.DataContext>
          <local:theParitySource />
      </ComboBox.DataContext>
  </ComboBox>
```

The combobox, however, remains empty (it is shown as empty, but seems to have the correct length), even though I can see in the Debugger how `theParitySource` gets populated. This approach does work in another combobox (even in the same class) where I do this for a baudrate. That I initialize with integer values, so I guess it is somehow related to the fact that I'm using an enum here, but I'm clueluess what might be the reason. Any pointers? Do I need to write a converter?

(Of course I can work around this by creating a list of strings from the enum, but this would be kind of unpleasant...)

Edit: actually I'd prefer to do all of this in XAML. Is there a simple way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this all in the `Xaml` using `ObjectDataProvider`

In your `Window.Resources` (or whatever resources you are using) setup a `ObjectDataProvider`.

To setup the `ObjectDataProvider` for `Enums` you set the `ObjectType` to `{x:Type sys:Enum}` and the `MethodName` to `GetValues` to fill the `ComboBox` with the actual `Enums` or you can use `GetNames` to fill the `ComboBox` with a string representaion of the `Enum`

```
   xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
   xmlns:io="clr-namespace:System.IO.Ports;assembly=System"

   <Window.Resources>

        <ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="ParityValues">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <x:Type TypeName="io:Parity" />
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>

    </Window.Resources>
```

Then bind to your ComboBox

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ParityValues}}" />
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this looks exactly as I want it to :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind to a proper path, you might be setting its data context, but you're not telling it with property to display.

You need to tell it what part of the bound context you are wanting to display and which you are wanting to be 'selected'.

[WPF Combobox DisplayMemberPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460612/wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath)

Comment: and you might want to check out MvvM model for doing this stuff, it's great for having a contained class that the view 'feeds off'.

Comment: I did not use a path for the baudrate either. This looks exactly the same and it does work.