# ComboBox with bound DisplayMember and ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf

I have `ComboBox` bound to `DataView` with DisplayMemberPath bound to some string property:

```
<ComboBox  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding SomeProperty}" ItemsSource="{Binding MyView}" />
```

My VM looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        dt.Columns.Add("MyColumn");
        dt.Rows.Add("AAA");
        dt.Rows.Add("BBB");
    }

    public DataView MyView
    {
        get { return dt.DefaultView; }
    }

    public string SomeProperty
    {
        get { return "MyColumn"; }
    }
}
```

Now I want to customize the `ItemTemplate`:

```
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Red" />
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=???}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Since the DisplayMemberPath is dynamic (and I can't use it with `ItemTemplate`), how do I specify the path?

EDIT:

This is my solution so far, but I think it's too complicated:

```
<ContentControl.Content>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource someMultiConverter}">
        <Binding Path="DataContext.SomeProperty" ElementName="comboBox1" />
        <Binding />
    </MultiBinding>
</ContentControl.Content>
```

And converter:

```
public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            string path = values[0] as string;
            DataRowView drv = values[1] as DataRowView;
            return drv[path].ToString();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're trying to get the `SomeProperty` value into `ContentControl.Content`?  Try this:

[StackOverflow WPF Combobox DisplayMemberPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460612/wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath)

You won't be able to set the same property twice, which appears to be what you're doing.  Basically, remove the `DisplayMemberPath` from:

```
<ComboBox  DisplayMemberPath="{Binding SomeProperty}"....
```

And set

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate >
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Rectangle Width="5" Height="5" Fill="Red" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MyColumn}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm trying to set `DataRowView[SomeProperty]` value to ContentControl.Content. From DataTemplate I have no access to SomeProperty, as it's a property of window's DataContext...

Comment: Please see my updated answer: I think you might try using a TextBlock instead of ContentControl.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work as the DataTemplate is actually bound to DataRowView, not MyViewModel. And DataRowView has no `SomeProperty` property.

Comment: Can you please try binding the TextBlock to your column name?  I've updated my answer again.

Comment: Your answer would work, the problem is I don't know the 'MyColumn' string value at compile time. It comes from SomeProperty which is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: Gotcha!  Now I think I understand the problem fully.  You need your column names to be dynamic?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes. Guess there's no easy solution. Thanks for your time, anyway!