# WPF Combobox Populated from LINQ To SQL Class Displaying Types Instead of Names

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq, data-binding

I have a WPF window with a combo box. The contents of the combo box should be populated from a column in a SQL table. I created a LINQ To SQL Data Context Class in a models folder and set the ItemsSource of the ComboBox to the class (Customers) generated by the data context.. But when I run the program, the contents of the combobox are the types of the items it pulled..

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using eTouchLV.GatekeeperUI.Models;

namespace eTouchLV.GatekeeperUI
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SQLDataClassDataContext dc = new SQLDataClassDataContext(Properties.Settings.Default.GatekeeperDBConnectionString);

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AssignDataToComponents();
        }

        private void AssignDataToComponents()
        {
            this.CheckDBIsValid();
            comboCustomers.ItemsSource = dc.Customers;
        }

        private void CheckDBIsValid()
        {
            if (!dc.DatabaseExists())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Program started on the machine but can't seem to find the database...", "Error connecting to DB on SQL server.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Program:
[image]

Comment: Ypu have many alternatives... Using the template binding for custom display of each item. Using the DisplayMemberPath property. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460612/wpf-combobox-displaymemberpath Or override the ToString method of the Customer class to return what you want to display

Comment: @jcvegan Hey thanks, I'll read that other post you shared. I will only use alternative method if it is really needed. I really like this technique because it is clean and I understand how it's working under the hood.